# When does a certain natural construction on monoidal categories yield a Hopf algebra?

Tags: ct.category-theory, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal C = (\mathcal C_0,\mathcal C_1)$ be a (small) strict monoidal category.  Pick a field $\mathbb K$, and let $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$ be the vector space with basis the morphism of $\mathcal C$.  It is an associative unital algebra under tensor product $\otimes$ (the identity morphism on the $\otimes$ unit is the algebra unit).

I will now define a coassociative comultiplication on $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$, although without restriction on $\mathcal C$ the comultiplication will not converge.  I'll give two descriptions:

1. $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$ is an associative algebra not only under $\otimes$, but also under composition: if $a,b \in \mathcal C_1$, then $ab = a\circ b$ if that composition is defined in $\mathcal C_1$, and $0$ otherwise.  But $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$ has a distinguished basis (namely $\mathcal C_1$), and hence a distinguished map $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1] \to (\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1])^\*$; using this map, turn the composition multiplication into a comultiplication.
2. For each morphism $c \in \mathcal C_1$, there is some set $\{(a,b)\in \mathcal C_1 \times \mathcal C_1 \text{ s.t. } a\circ b = c \}$ of ways to factorize $c$.  Define $\Delta(c) = \sum_\{ a\circ b = c \} a\otimes b$; where here the $\otimes$ is the exterior one (not the other multiplication on $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$.

From either description, it's clear that the comultiplication isn't really defined: in general that sum diverges.  So let's suppose that $\mathcal C$ has the property that any morphism has only finitely many factorizations.  Clearly this requirement is [evil](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/evil).

> **Question 0:** Is there a less evil way to talk about this comultiplication?  Actually, even the requirement that $\mathcal C$ be strict is evil, but without it $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$ is not associative.  Is there a less evil fix for this?

The comultiplication is co-unital.  The counit on $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$ sends identity morphisms to $1\in \mathbb K$ and non-identity morphisms to $0$.  (A less-evilization might want to send, say, isomorphisms to $1$, or something.)

So, I have a vector space $\mathbb K[C_1]$ with a multiplication (coming from the monoidal structure on $\mathcal C$) and a comultiplication (coming from the composition structure on $\mathcal C$).

> **Question 1:** Are there simple general conditions that assure that this structure is a bialgebra?

In the categories I am most interested in, $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$ is a bialgebra.  My intuition is that when $\mathcal C$ is sufficiently free, everything works.  Here's an example.  The category of *braided graphs* has objects the non-negative integers, thought of as distinguished subsets of $\mathbb R$.  A morphism between $m$ and $n$ is: a graph $G$ with $m$ univalent vertices marked "in" and $n$ univalent vertices marked "out", along with a smooth embedding $G \to \mathbb R^2 \times [0,1]$ so that $G \cap \mathbb R^2 \times\{0\}$ consists of precisely the $m$ "in" vertices, spaced out on the integers $\{1,\dots,m\} \times \{0\} \times \{0\}$, and similarly for the out vertices, and such that every edge of $G$ is never horizontal.  Two morphisms are identified if they are isotopic rel boundary among embedded graphs with non-horizonal edges.  Composition are the monoidal structure are obvious.  Equivalently, the category of braided graphs is the free braided monoidal category generated by a single basic object $V$ and a basic morphism in each $\hom (V^{\otimes m}, V^{\otimes n})$.

In any case, once you have a bialgebra, you are lead inexorably to the following question:

> **Question 2:** When is $\mathbb K[\mathcal C_1]$ Hopf?

For very free categories, it is Hopf: a free category is graded, by setting the generators to have grading $1$; the degree-zero part is $\mathbb K[\text{identity maps}]$, and these themselves are graded by the number of objects; the degree-zero part of this is $\mathbb K$, generated by the identity map on the monoidal unit; then [bootstrap back up](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10827/).  Probably this works for less-free things too, using filtrations rather than gradings (i.e. filtered quotients of free monoidal categories).

Comment: Is being a Hopf algebra a property?  I thought it was a structure.

Comment: @Qiaochu:  "Hopf" is property.  An antipode on a bialgebra is unique if it exists.  This is similar to how being "group" is a property of monoids.

Comment: (Re: Hopf is a property)  For example, I learned at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10827/ that a filtered bialgebra with Hopf 0-part is Hopf.  Application: formal bialgebra deformations of Hopf algebras are Hopf.

Comment: Something about question 1 doesn't seem right to me.  When I figure out what it is, I will write.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how question (1) could have a positive answer, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Let me write $\Delta$ for the co-product you proposed, dual to $\circ$.  For simplicity, let me adopt description (2) of $\Delta$.  Since the tensor product of morphisms is used for multiplication in the algebra, I'll use ``\boxtimes'' to denote the tensor product on vector spaces and their elements (clunky notation, sorry; also for some reason in paragraph mode, \boxtimes shows as "A-hat" so I didn't LaTex it above).  We have:

$$\Delta(f\otimes g) = \sum_{a,b|ab=f\otimes g} a \boxtimes b,$$

while 
$$\Delta(f)\otimes \Delta(g) = \sum_{x,y,z,w|xy=f,zw=g}x\otimes z \boxtimes y\otimes w$$

Now it's true that every summand appearing in the second sum is the sort of summand appearing in the first sum.  However, a given $a\boxtimes b$ in the first sum will appear many times, e.g. as $a\otimes id\boxtimes b\otimes id$ and $id \otimes a \boxtimes b\otimes id$.  I don't see how they could be equal, then.

Comment: You're totally right, for general monoidal categories.  This is why I want my category to be very strict: then $a\otimes \text{id} = a$, and so the summand appears only once.

Comment: Or, rather, I hope that there is a weaker construction, that probably takes place at a higher category-number.  (But my [category number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-category_number) is $2+\epsilon$, so I hope the answer to question 0 doesn't go beyond there.  My main question is at the $1+\epsilon$ level.)

Comment: Theo, I think that David is saying that the map $a\boxtimes b$ will appear with coefficient at least two in the second sum, because it is equal to $(a\otimes 1)\boxtimes(b\otimes 1)$ and to $(1\otimes a)\boxtimes(b\otimes 1)$, which correspond to $(x,y,z,w)=(a,b,1,1)$ and $(x,y,z,w)=(1,b,a,1)$, two different summands.

Comment: @Theo: "then $a\otimes id =a$ and so the summand only appears once".  I was assuming strictness in my answer, and that thist equality holds: this is what leads to the problem.  That particular contradiction was cooked up just to illustrate that there is a problem in the axioms here.  Essentially, you've started with a vector space $K[C_1]$ which has three products, "+","$\otimes$, and $\circ$, with various distributive properties like $f\otimes g \circ h\times k= f\circ h \otimes g\circ k$, and used duality to make one of the structures a co-product.  I don't think this yields a bi-algebra.

Comment: Probably someone with more expertise could spell out more clearly what structure arises here.  Can you clarify in the example about embedded graphs how one shows that $\Delta$ is a homomorphism?  It might help me understand.

Comment: I certainly don't think one usually gets a bialgebra by doing what I describe.  But I still don't understand your counterexample, at least in the situation where there are very few morphisms.  Suppose for example that $\Delta(f) = \sum f_{(1)}\boxtimes f_{(2)}$ and $\Delta(g) = \sum g_{(1)}\boxtimes g_{(2)}$.  Then in general $f\otimes g$ has many factorizations that do not split as tensor products, but supposing it doesn't (e.g. in the free case), then a factorization of $f\otimes g$ is definitely of the form $(f_{(1)}\otimes g_{(1)}) \boxtimes (f_{(2)}\otimes g_{(2)})$.

Comment: In Mariano's comment and your last paragraph, on the one hand you say that $a\circ b = f\otimes g$, and then you say that $a\circ b = f$ and $id \circ \id = g$, and then you say that $a\circ id = f$ and $id \circ b = g$.